# Ovs with dpdk configuration issue

Tags: dpdk, ovs-dpdk

I installed dpdk 22.07 version on ubuntu 22.04 server as specified in the guide.

https://core.dpdk.org/doc/quick-start/

Then I used the following command for ovs installation.

```
./configure --with-dpdk=static CFLAGS="-Ofast -msse4.2 -mpopcnt"
```

And I got the following error.

configure: error: Could not find DPDK libraries in static/lib

Then I changed the command as follows.

```
./configure --with-dpdk=/opt/DPDK/dpdk-22.07 CFLAGS="-Ofast -msse4.2 -mpopcnt"
```

And I got the following error.

configure: error: Could not find DPDK libraries in /opt/DPDK/dpdk-22.07/lib

How can i solve this problem?

Note: Dpdk is located in /opt/DPDK/dpdk-22.07 path, and ovs is located in /opt/OVS//openvswitch-2.8.1 path.

Output of "pkg-config --static --libs --cflags libdpdk" command is below.

```
-I/usr/local/include -include rte_config.h -march=native -Wl,--whole-archive -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:librte_common_cpt.a -l:librte_common_dpaax.a -l:librte_common_iavf.a -l:librte_common_octeontx.a -l:librte_bus_auxiliary.a -l:librte_bus_dpaa.a -l:librte_bus_fslmc.a -l:librte_bus_ifpga.a -l:librte_bus_pci.a -l:librte_bus_vdev.a -l:librte_bus_vmbus.a -l:librte_common_cnxk.a -l:librte_common_qat.a -l:librte_common_sfc_efx.a -l:librte_mempool_bucket.a -l:librte_mempool_cnxk.a -l:librte_mempool_dpaa.a -l:librte_mempool_dpaa2.a -l:librte_mempool_octeontx.a -l:librte_mempool_ring.a -l:librte_mempool_stack.a -l:librte_dma_cnxk.a -l:librte_dma_dpaa.a -l:librte_dma_dpaa2.a -l:librte_dma_hisilicon.a -l:librte_dma_idxd.a -l:librte_dma_ioat.a -l:librte_dma_skeleton.a -l:librte_net_af_packet.a -l:librte_net_ark.a -l:librte_net_atlantic.a -l:librte_net_avp.a -l:librte_net_axgbe.a -l:librte_net_bnx2x.a -l:librte_net_bnxt.a -l:librte_net_bond.a -l:librte_net_cnxk.a -l:librte_net_cxgbe.a -l:librte_net_dpaa.a -l:librte_net_dpaa2.a -l:librte_net_e1000.a -l:librte_net_ena.a -l:librte_net_enetc.a -l:librte_net_enetfec.a -l:librte_net_enic.a -l:librte_net_failsafe.a -l:librte_net_fm10k.a -l:librte_net_hinic.a -l:librte_net_hns3.a -l:librte_net_i40e.a -l:librte_net_iavf.a -l:librte_net_ice.a -l:librte_net_igc.a -l:librte_net_ionic.a -l:librte_net_ixgbe.a -l:librte_net_kni.a -l:librte_net_liquidio.a -l:librte_net_memif.a -l:librte_net_netvsc.a -l:librte_net_nfp.a -l:librte_net_ngbe.a -l:librte_net_null.a -l:librte_net_octeontx.a -l:librte_net_octeontx_ep.a -l:librte_net_pcap.a -l:librte_net_pfe.a -l:librte_net_qede.a -l:librte_net_ring.a -l:librte_net_sfc.a -l:librte_net_softnic.a -l:librte_net_tap.a -l:librte_net_thunderx.a -l:librte_net_txgbe.a -l:librte_net_vdev_netvsc.a -l:librte_net_vhost.a -l:librte_net_virtio.a -l:librte_net_vmxnet3.a -l:librte_raw_cnxk_bphy.a -l:librte_raw_cnxk_gpio.a -l:librte_raw_dpaa2_cmdif.a -l:librte_raw_ntb.a -l:librte_raw_skeleton.a -l:librte_crypto_bcmfs.a -l:librte_crypto_caam_jr.a -l:librte_crypto_ccp.a -l:librte_crypto_cnxk.a -l:librte_crypto_dpaa_sec.a -l:librte_crypto_dpaa2_sec.a -l:librte_crypto_nitrox.a -l:librte_crypto_null.a -l:librte_crypto_octeontx.a -l:librte_crypto_openssl.a -l:librte_crypto_scheduler.a -l:librte_crypto_virtio.a -l:librte_compress_octeontx.a -l:librte_compress_zlib.a -l:librte_regex_cn9k.a -l:librte_vdpa_ifc.a -l:librte_vdpa_sfc.a -l:librte_event_cnxk.a -l:librte_event_dlb2.a -l:librte_event_dpaa.a -l:librte_event_dpaa2.a -l:librte_event_dsw.a -l:librte_event_opdl.a -l:librte_event_skeleton.a -l:librte_event_sw.a -l:librte_event_octeontx.a -l:librte_baseband_acc100.a -l:librte_baseband_fpga_5gnr_fec.a -l:librte_baseband_fpga_lte_fec.a -l:librte_baseband_la12xx.a -l:librte_baseband_null.a -l:librte_baseband_turbo_sw.a -l:librte_node.a -l:librte_graph.a -l:librte_flow_classify.a -l:librte_pipeline.a -l:librte_table.a -l:librte_pdump.a -l:librte_port.a -l:librte_fib.a -l:librte_ipsec.a -l:librte_vhost.a -l:librte_stack.a -l:librte_security.a -l:librte_sched.a -l:librte_reorder.a -l:librte_rib.a -l:librte_dmadev.a -l:librte_regexdev.a -l:librte_rawdev.a -l:librte_power.a -l:librte_pcapng.a -l:librte_member.a -l:librte_lpm.a -l:librte_latencystats.a -l:librte_kni.a -l:librte_jobstats.a -l:librte_ip_frag.a -l:librte_gso.a -l:librte_gro.a -l:librte_gpudev.a -l:librte_eventdev.a -l:librte_efd.a -l:librte_distributor.a -l:librte_cryptodev.a -l:librte_compressdev.a -l:librte_cfgfile.a -l:librte_bpf.a -l:librte_bitratestats.a -l:librte_bbdev.a -l:librte_acl.a -l:librte_timer.a -l:librte_hash.a -l:librte_metrics.a -l:librte_cmdline.a -l:librte_pci.a -l:librte_ethdev.a -l:librte_meter.a -l:librte_net.a -l:librte_mbuf.a -l:librte_mempool.a -l:librte_rcu.a -l:librte_ring.a -l:librte_eal.a -l:librte_telemetry.a -l:librte_kvargs.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--export-dynamic -latomic -Wl,--as-needed -lrte_node -lrte_graph -lrte_flow_classify -lrte_pipeline -lrte_table -lrte_pdump -lrte_port -lrte_fib -lrte_ipsec -lrte_vhost -lrte_stack -lrte_security -lrte_sched -lrte_reorder -lrte_rib -lrte_dmadev -lrte_regexdev -lrte_rawdev -lrte_power -lrte_pcapng -lrte_member -lrte_lpm -lrte_latencystats -lrte_kni -lrte_jobstats -lrte_ip_frag -lrte_gso -lrte_gro -lrte_gpudev -lrte_eventdev -lrte_efd -lrte_distributor -lrte_cryptodev -lrte_compressdev -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_bpf -lrte_bitratestats -lrte_bbdev -lrte_acl -lrte_timer -lrte_hash -lrte_metrics -lrte_cmdline -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_rcu -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_telemetry -lrte_kvargs -pthread -lm -ldl -lnuma -lcrypto -ldl -pthread -lz -lpcap -ldbus-1
```

Comment: have you build and installed DPDK-22.07 in the system? Can you please run `pkg-config --static --libs --cflags libdpdk` and update the question too?

Comment: Yes. I added the output.

Comment: ideally the OVS when configured for DPDK using `with-dpdk`  should be checking for pkg-config and using the same. In your case it is failing, very strange. Are you using namespace or different bash where there is possibility for pkg-config for libdpdk fails?

Comment: I'm trying to configure it over SSH connection. Could this be the problem? ( No. I tried it on the server's own terminal, the result is the same)

Comment: looks like there is issue with `configure `. can you share the version for `OVS` to check